# Use a part of an output as input

Tags: python, api, finance, alpha-vantage

I am looking for something i am not able to fix:

I have a code that is loading data via an API andreturns the last known price of Bitcoin, and other information. The code is :

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
    'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
    'from_currency': 'XRP', 
    'to_currency': 'EUR',
    'apikey': AV_API_KEY
})
resp

resp.json()
```

When I execute the code, I have this output :

```
{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': {'1. From_Currency Code': 'BTC',
   '2. From_Currency Name': 'Bitcoin',
   '3. To_Currency Code': 'EUR',
   '4. To_Currency Name': 'Euro',
   '5. Exchange Rate': '14322.63532',
   '6. Last Refreshed': '2020-11-27 22:59:05',
   '7. Time Zone': 'UTC',
   '8. Bid Price': '0.46113245',
   '9. Ask Price': '0.46117422'}}
```

I want to use only the Exchange Rate value (14322.63532) to then compare it to the Exchange Rate two minutes later, to know the % variation.

Do someone have any clue to how I can isolate the Exchange Rate of the rest of the output ?

Thank you !

EDIT :

I tried this

```
newdict = {} 
newdict['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']
```

but i have
KeyError: 'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'

Comment: That looks like a dict.  Try `mydict['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']` (use whatever name you gave the variable instead of `mydict`)

Comment: @JohnGordon ok thanks. I tried this . 
newdict = {}
newdict["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]['5. Exchange Rate']
but i have KeyError: 'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'

Comment: You say you "have this output" - how do you have it in your code? What's holding it? The `newdict` you define is empty, so of course it cannot find any key - how are you loading the data? You say you "have a code", please share the relevant part here.

Comment: You need to be referencing the elements of the original dict, not the new dict.

Comment: @Grismar I am loading the data through an API, the code is : resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
    'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
    'from_currency': 'BTC', 
    'to_currency': 'EUR',
    'apikey': AV_API_KEY
})
resp

resp.json()

Answer (score 0):

`newdict` needs to be the output you showed, not an empty dictionary.

```
newdict = {'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': {'1. From_Currency Code': 'BTC',
   '2. From_Currency Name': 'Bitcoin',
   '3. To_Currency Code': 'EUR',
   '4. To_Currency Name': 'Euro',
   '5. Exchange Rate': '14322.63532',
   '6. Last Refreshed': '2020-11-27 22:59:05',
   '7. Time Zone': 'UTC',
   '8. Bid Price': '0.46113245',
   '9. Ask Price': '0.46117422'}
}
print(float(newdict['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']))
```

Comment: Ok thank you it works! Is there any other way to do it ? Because I want to extract and print ['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']) automatically after I get the Exchange Rate, without copy-pasting all the output. Is it possible ?

Comment: If you're getting the data from an API, you don't have to cut and paste anything, it's already in the variable.

Comment: I see. If I print the API code each 2 minutes, do you know If I can compare the old and new output Exchange Rate ?

Comment: Save the previous exchange rate in a variable like `prev_exchange_rate`, then use `float(newdict['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate']) - prev_exchange_rate`